# How to avoid dict to the list convertion?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the list with email addresses. I should calculate a count of each email address in the list and present that in the list like below (Google Analytics format):

```
[["to99@example.com", "260"], ["to54@example.com", "4"], ["to30@example.com", "3"],
["to16@example.com", "2"], ["to77@example.com", "2"], ["to78@example.com", "2"],
["to76@example.com", "1"], ["to32@example.com", "1"], ["to24@example.com", "1"]]
```

(will not contain more than 100 records)

I do it in the following way:

```
# count number of emails
addressees = {}
for i in emails:
    if i.to in addressees: addressees[i.to] += 1
    else: addressees[i.to] = 1
```

In result I get the dict like below:

```
{u'to23@example.com': 2, u'to50@example.com': 3, u'to77@example.com': 6, 
 u'to99@example.com': 102, u'to72@example.com': 1, u'to46@example.com': 1,
 u'to33@example.com': 1, u'to78@example.com': 1, u'to56@example.com': 1,
 u'to54@example.com': 2}
```

And then convert it to the list format I need:

```
addressees_list = []
for addr in iter(addressees):
    addressees_list.append([addr, str(addressees[addr])])
```

It looks awful. Is there any way to generate the list from the beginning? I will also need to sort the final list by counter value.

Comment: Does your ```list with email addresses``` contain strings or email objects? Can you provide an example? ... nevermind, i should have looked at your example code closer.

Answer (score 5):

Not really, unless you first sort your email addresses; this'd be a O(NlogN) solution to a problem where using a mapping gives you a O(N) approach instead.

There is a more pythonic way to produce your output:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(i.to for i in emails)
addressees_list = [[addr, str(count)] for addr, count in counts.most_common()]
```

The [`collections.Counter()` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) lets you collect those counts with a single line of code (extracting the `.to` attribute for each email object), and the [`Counter.most_common()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) produces your desired output *in sorted order*.

Demo extracted from your desired dataset:

```
>>> # expand email counts into a sequence of emails matching those counts
...
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> dataset = [["to99@example.com", "260"], ["to54@example.com", "4"], ["to30@example.com", "3"],
... ["to16@example.com", "2"], ["to77@example.com", "2"], ["to78@example.com", "2"],
... ["to76@example.com", "1"], ["to32@example.com", "1"], ["to24@example.com", "1"]]
>>> dataset = [e for e, count in dataset for _ in range(int(count))]
>>> shuffle(dataset)
>>> # actual counting
... 
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(dataset)
>>> [[addr, str(count)] for addr, count in counts.most_common()]
[['to99@example.com', '260'], ['to54@example.com', '4'], ['to30@example.com', '3'], ['to78@example.com', '2'], ['to77@example.com', '2'], ['to16@example.com', '2'], ['to24@example.com', '1'], ['to32@example.com', '1'], ['to76@example.com', '1']]
```

The inefficient approach, as a one-liner, requires you to sort *twice*, once to group the email addresses for in-line counting, the other to then sort the resulting counted email addresses; `Counter.most_common()` uses sort too, but then you sort just once.

As a one-liner, that'd be:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

[(e, str(c))
 for e, c in sorted(([email, sum(1 for _ in group)]
                     for email, group in groupby(sorted(i.to for i in emails))),
                     key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)]
```

which really does look awful, apart from the inefficiencies of the approach.

Comment: missing bracket after ```str(count)```

Comment: You have an odd definition of "one line"... :P

Comment: @Veedrac: one expression, then. The newlines can be removed and it'll still work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misinterpreting your question, but you could try this:

```
from collections import Counter
addresses = ['to99@example.com', 'to54@example.com', 'to54@example.com', ]

[(k, v) for k, v in Counter(addresses).most_common()]
```

---

**Output :**  `[('to54@example.com', 2), ('to99@example.com', 1)]`